# Creating single installer for a multiple MSI's?

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer

I have three different MSI's created to deploy my project. My end result is to run a single exe that will call the rest three MSI's, with the current running installation description or name. As same as we see while Visual Studio Installation.

I have tried WIX but didn't come up with anything. Please guide.

Environment - Visual Studio 2008 / 2010 with Win 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a bootstrapper (sometimes called a chainer). There are many available, including open-source ones like [DotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) and WiX's [Burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn).

Answer (score 0):

You could create one MSI and combine all you project's primary outputs. If you need to separate them just add a folder for each project's primary outputs.